# How do I derive parametric functions for drawing a curve given by an equation?

Tags: graphing-functions, parametric

If I have an equation in two unknowns, such as
$$2x^4 + yx^2 + y^4 = 2$$
how do I derive the two corresponding parametric functions $x(y)$ and $y(t)$ that I could use for drawing the curve that the equation represents? The simple approach I seem to find everywhere of setting $x(t) = t$ and simply isolating $y(t)$ correspondingly from the equation does not seem to work for me here due to the $xy^2$ product term.

Comment: Which is it $xy^2$ or $x^2y$? In the former case let $y(t)=t$ and solve for $x(t)$ (use the quadratic formula to solve for $x^2(t)$ first and then take a square root) in the latter let $x(t)=t$ and solve for $y(t)$ (use the quadratic formula to solve for $y^2(t)$ first and then take a square root).

Comment: Thomas. Not simple.Set z=x^2, and y=t. You can solve your quadratic equation z_1,z_2 in terms of t (and, square roots of t expression.You take?

Comment: Thanks, your comments helped me build some useable parametric functions.